# Update Google slide training suite using scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I have a series of Google slide decks which form a training pathway and we need to update them asap but don't have a lot of time for donkey work.

Our brand colours have recently updated and I would like to check if we could use Google Scripts to update each deck.

It would essentially be a find and replace exercise - find one hex and replace with another. Is this possible and, if so, how can we achieve this? I haven't used scripts before but am usually a quick learner!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Questions on this site should be about a specific problem that the asker is facing; in this case, you should have looked at the Google Slides help first, and when you get stuck, come here with a specific question. The official guide to using Apps Script in Google Slides is https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides.